# Bi-directional Three State IO and microprocessor gpio

Tags: gpio, tri-state, bidirectional

I want to use an MP5010B Electronic Fuse IC. I will enable or disable it by using the Enable/Fault pin which is billed as a bi-directional three state IO.

I will enable or disable this pin using a microprocessor such as an AVR with a GPIO pin.

I also want to monitor the status of the efuse with the same microprocessor.

The relevant part of the IC data sheet that explains the functioning of the enable/fault pin is extraced here:

The  Enable/Fault  pin  is  a  bi-directional,  three-
level I/O with a weak pull-up current (25μA, typ.).
The  three  levels  are  LOW,  MID,  and  HIGH.  It
functions  to  enable/disable  the  part  and  to  relay
fault information.

**Enable/Fault as an input:**

1. LOW and MID disable the part.
2. LOW,  in  addition  to  disabling  the  part,
   clears the fault flag.
3. HIGH enables the part (if the fault flag is
   clear).

**Enable/Fault as an output:**

1. The  pull-up  current  will  allow  a  “wired
   nor”  pull-up  to  enable  the  part  (if  not
   overridden).
2. An  under-voltage  condition  will  cause  a
   LOW  on  the  Enable/Fault  pin,  and  will
   clear the fault flag.
3. A  thermal  fault  will  set  a  MID  on  the
   Enable/Fault  pin,  and  will  set  the  fault
   flag

I do not understand how to employ both this input and this output function at the same time on the AVR.  Could someone explain how this interface will look electrically between a 3.3V Arduino and this electronic fuse chip including the state of any internal pullups if needed on the AVR pin ?

Comment: Use an ADC input to measure the voltage. This can also be used as gpio.

Comment: The datasheet has a circuit diagram that is quite straightforward when considered with the text. I would drive the pin with an open drain output GPIO as an internal fault can drive the pin low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "pin functions" table shows what you should do:

> Enable/Fault. A tri-state, bi-directional interface. Leave floating to enable  the output. Pull to ground (using an open drain or open collector device) to disable the output. If a thermal fault occurs, this voltage enters an intermediate state to signal that the device is in thermal shutdown.

So your GPIO must never actively drive high.

- When you want to disable the fuse, configure the GPIO as low output.
- When you want to enable the fuse, configure the GPIO as an input (this is the only way to prevent it from driving high).
- Using the ACR's ADC to monitor for the fault condition would be difficult because the ADC requires a signal with an impedance of less than 10 kΩ. You *can* use a digital input if the switching threshold is below 1.95 V.

Comment: just because the impedance is higher than the nominal 10k does not preclude the use of the ADC. The ADC input impedance is specified as beyond that the ADC errors will increase due to the RC time constant of the sampling capacitor. Besides, putting a couple of nF of capacitance on the ADC input satisfies the impedance requirement.